# Difference between "give them a cheer" and "cheer them up"

Tags: phrases

Is it more common to say that way written on the left rather than those written on the right?  If so, please let me know why.

```
give him a hug       hug him
give him a smile     smile at him
give him a cheer     cheer him up
```

Comment: LOL: _Give him a chop - chop him up_

Comment: How is this off-topic?!

Answer (score 3):

*Give him a cheer* and *cheer him up* mean different things. The first means ‘give him a shout of encouragement’. The second means ‘do something to make him feel happier’.

There’s not the same difference with your other examples, but they would be used in different contexts.

Comment: Thank you.  Then, do you mean that give him a hug is different from hug him?

Comment: No, that is the same - it is also not hug him up

Comment: _Give him a hug_ and _hug him_ describe the same action, but I would not like to say that they were interchangeable in all contexts.

Comment: +1 As you say. However, I believe the examples were just that -- examples. The OP is basically interested in the difference between the structures.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now it is clear.  That was a big help.

Answer (score 1):

The first two examples are equivalent.  The third may or may not, but this is because the word "cheer" as a noun has multiple meanings, which differ depending upon context

- "to hug" as a verb means "to give a hug"
- "to smile" as a verb means "to give a smile"
- "to cheer" may mean "to give a cheer" but it may also mean "to cheer up"

See the various meanings of ["cheer" at Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cheer?s=t).

1. a shout of encouragement, approval, congratulation, etc.: The cheers of the fans filled the stadium.
2. a set or traditional form of shout used by spectators to encourage or show enthusiasm for an athletic team, contestant, etc., as rah! rah! rah!
3. something that gives joy or gladness; encouragement; comfort: words of cheer.
4. a state of feeling or spirits: Their good cheer overcame his depression.
5. gladness, gaiety, or animation: full of cheer and good spirits.

Thus, to give a cheer might cheer someone up, but it might not.  If you give a cheer for your team, it might cheer your team up, but it will not cheer up your team's opponents!  If you shout the cheer "Hip, hip hooray!" to a depressed person it may not cheer him up at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cyberherbalist.  That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The pairs are different in what the author means to convey, though in the examples the actions may be the same. Each of the two structures has its uses in appropriate contexts. For one, it is the controlling verb that gets the focus of the statement.

**give** him a hug
*vs.*
**hug** him